# Nadamunigal’s contribution to Thiruvaimozhi

Tags: sri-vaishnava, alwar, nathamuni

Nadamunigal was instrumental  in bringing the Thiruvaimozhi composed by Namalwar when no one recited during that time itself. What was the methodology adopted by Nadhamuni to make people recite Thiruvaimozhi?

Comment: I am surprised to seethe negative ranking.Because when people of yesteryears forgot thiruvaimozhi nadamuni brought back for recitation.Thatis what I asked.